# How can I determine whether a Subversion repository was created with a BDB or fsfs backend?

Tags: svn, berkeley-db, fsfs

If you arrive at a pre-existing Subversion repository, how can you determine whether it was created with a BDB or fsfs backend storage method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open the file `repository\db\fs-type` with a text editor. It either contains `bdb` or `fsfs` indicating which backend it uses.